# Faild to save a xlxs file twice with comments using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

This is my codes. When I try to save a xlxs with comments, It failed. How can I know when to save again.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime


filename = u"large_table.xlsx"

model = load_workbook(filename)
model.properties.lastPrinted = datetime.datetime.now()
model.save(filename)
model.properties.lastPrinted = datetime.datetime.now()
model.save(filename)
```

**Traceback**: It seems that `self.workbook.vba_archive` is set to None unexpectedly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/h32workspace/trunk/event_editor/eric6/model/test_file.py", line 31, in <module>
    model.save(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 342, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 269, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 251, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 81, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 214, in _write_worksheets
    self._write_comment(ws)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 184, in _write_comment
    vml = fromstring(self.workbook.vba_archive.read(ws.legacy_drawing))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I tried to use `keep_vba=True` to load workbook, but if failed to save file correctly. The saved file can not be opened.

Comment: Try using XlsxWriter: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter

Comment: From the traceback it's quite clear that the code posted is incorrect: you're working with an XLSM file and these are not entirely covered by the standard because all the macro-related stuff is a black box.

Comment: @CharlieClark I found that excel with comments will fail to save twice

Comment: Yes, but the problem is related to using macros.

Answer (score 3):

I used your code to save a sample *.xlsx* file. It saved without any issues.
Do you have any `macro` within you *.xlsx* file?
If yes, you may want to open the xlsx file with macro enabled using

```
model = load_workbook(filename, keep_vba=True)
```

See [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=keep_vba#write-a-workbook-from-xltm-as-xlsm) for details on `openpyxl` usage with macro.

Also, try to save to a different filename than trying to overwrite original to make sure it works correctly.

```
fileout = "test2.xlsx"
model.save(fileout)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: when use `keep_vab=True`. After save file twice, the file is broken

Comment: why do you need to save the file twice?  You can save it just once at the end. Unless you are modifying the xlsx file after saving first time. In which case you will need to open it again and save after that. The xlsx object has original information prior to first save.

Comment: I choose to close and open again

Comment: ok- in that case, after closing open again , do you mods and close again. Hopefully that may take care of any corruption.